# Customizing print preview

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

According to [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aabc3hc6.aspx), the print preview dialogbar can be customized. My question is, can I add another dialogbar on print preview frame ? Or at least, can I move the existing one on the left side of the frame ? (Right now it is at the top of the frame).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you derive your own class from [CPreviewView](http://www.cppdoc.com/example/mfc/classdoc/MFC/CPreviewView.html), you can customize its processing.  Looking closer at the base class, you'll see that it exposes a protected CDialogBar member (m_pToolBar).  Theoretically, you should be able to use the embedded dialog bar and change its orientation from the parent frame.  Whether you should do that or not, is another question.  Typically, the dialog bar is updated to include some additional buttons, and, not re-docked elsewhere.  And, if you need a second dialog bar, I'd probably question that requirement also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finally I made it:

```
VERIFY(m_dlgBar.Create(pWndFrame, IDD_MY_DIALOGBAR, CBRS_LEFT, AFX_IDW_PREVIEW_BAR));
```

Thank you.